# Error while building cvblobs.lib with VS2010 and Windows7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, cvblobslib

I am trying to build **cvblobslib** in VS2010 with windows 7.
The **cvblobs** wiki page here

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib#Build_intructions

describes that to build you need to just open the project file and build it.However, for me working in VS2010 on windows 7 this does not build and gives the following error:

```
`c:\users\administrator\desktop\cvblobslib_opencv_v8_3\blob.h(21): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cxcore.h': No such file or directory
1>  ComponentLabeling.cpp

1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\cvblobslib_opencv_v8_3\blobcontour.h(6): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cv.h': No such file or directory
1>  BlobResult.cpp

1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\cvblobslib_opencv_v8_3\blobresult.h(24): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cxcore.h': No such file or directory
1>  BlobOperators.cpp

1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\cvblobslib_opencv_v8_3\blob.h(21): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cxcore.h': No such file or directory
1>  BlobContour.cpp

1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\cvblobslib_opencv_v8_3\blobcontour.h(6): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cv.h': No such file or directory
1>  Generating Code...
1>
1>Build FAILED.`
```

How do I remove these errors?There have been similar questions here but no-one has answered these satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the include paths to point to your installation of OpenCV (`opencv_install_path/include/`)? This resides in Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.

Also specify the path to OpenCV libs (`opencv_install_path/lib/`) in Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories and specify the static libs (`opencv*.lib`) that you need to use in Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.